# Uncaught ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker

Why do I keep getting this error?

I should be able to use this global function right?

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

I'm using chrome.

I'm using https://code.google.com/p/bitjs/ and it begins with

```
importScripts('io.js');
importScripts('archive.js');
```

Comment: How do you spawn the worker?

Comment: Thought this would spawn a worker? This is how they use it in https://code.google.com/p/bitjs/source/browse/unzip.js

Comment: No, this needs to be inside a worker script. See https://code.google.com/p/bitjs/source/browse/archive.js#278 on how they do it, or follow the tutorials you've linked

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This code needs to be inside a worker script. The worker itself is created via a new `Worker` object - see [*Getting Started* in the tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-gettingstarted).

The code you've linked is inside the worker created [here](http://code.google.com/p/bitjs/source/browse/archive.js#278).

Answer (score 52):

When you create a worker it is actually executed twice.  The first pass is in the context of the global 'window' object(meaning you have access to all the window object functions).  The second call through is in the context of the worker which has a different global object, one where 'importScripts' exists.

```
// proper initialization
if( 'function' === typeof importScripts) {
   importScripts('script2.js');
   addEventListener('message', onMessage);

   function onMessage(e) { 
     // do some work here 
   }    
}
```

Notice the addEventListener is inside the if statement.  If you place it outside of it, your callback will be registered twice.  Once on the 'window' global and once on the worker's global.

Happy coding!

Comment: your answer make sense. can you please point me some links to know more about the twice execution.

Comment: Make sure you are spelling the function 'importScripts' correctly.  Capitalization is important.

Answer (score 16):

I encountered this error as well. In my case, it is because I am testing the code using Karma/Jasmine. Due to the test framework, the worker.js file is loaded by main thread as well.

I avoided this error by wrappig the worker.js file with:

```
    if( 'undefined' === typeof window){
       importScripts('workerscript2.js');
    ...
    }
```

Please refer to the comment below by Rob, which offers an alternative solution.

Comment: Consider using `'function' === typeof importScripts` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the giving the solution to avoid error. I am new so unable to vote but writing it, I just replace my line `importScripts('Myworkerscript.js');` to

```
 if( 'undefined' === typeof window){
   importScripts('Myworkerscript.js');
}
```

and a magic is happend and error were gone.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the linting issue you're facing, you can add the following comment in the file containing importScripts

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
```