# WorkboxSW constructor throws error Undefined

Tags: progressive-web-apps, sw-precache, workbox, sw-toolbox

In my service worker file, I am using this code:

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.0.0-beta.2/workbox-sw.js");
const workbox = new WorkboxSW();
```

But I am getting error **`Uncaught ReferenceError: WorkboxSW is not defined`** hence my service worker is not registering.

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500091/uncaught-referenceerror-importscripts-is-not-defined), when you create a worker it is actually executed twice. The first pass is in the context of the global `window` object(meaning you have access to all the window object functions). The second call through is in the context of the worker which has a different global object, one where `importScripts` exists. You may want to check this [documentation](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-gettingstarted) for reference.

Answer (score 4):

In Workbox v3, you won't normally explicitly construct a `WorkboxSW` instance. Instead, there's a `workbox` variable exposed in the global scope that provides the interface to the library.

Here's an example, excepted from the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v2#workbox-sw):

> Previously in v2:

```
importScripts('<path to workbox-sw>/importScripts/workbox-sw.prod.v2.1.3.js');

const workbox = new WorkboxSW({
  skipWaiting: true,
  clientsClaim: true,
  // etc.
});

workbox.router.registerRoute(...);
```

> In v3, you just have to import the workbox-sw.js script, and a ready-to-use instance will be automatically available in the global namespace as workbox:

```
importScripts('<path to workbox-sw>/3.0.0/workbox-sw.js');

// workbox is implicitly created and ready for use.
workbox.routing.registerRoute(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but in my case, my sw was registering despite the error message. Adding type="javascript/worker" like this: `<script type="javascript/worker" src="sw.js"></script>` at my entry point, removed the error in dev tools.